# How to reduce "if statement" conditions? [reduce the conditions inside the if statement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop, multiple-conditions

after days of hard thinking i choose to ask that question. I have `if` statement with multiple conditions:

```
//var current is array of arrays of integers
if((current[rot][0] + x)<blocks.length 
    && (current[rot][1] + x)<blocks.length 
    && (current[rot][2] + x)<blocks.length 
    && (current[rot][3] + x)<blocks.length
    && !$(blocks[current[rot][0]+x]).hasClass("blockLand") 
    && !$(blocks[current[rot][1]+x]).hasClass("blockLand")
    && !$(blocks[current[rot][2]+x]).hasClass("blockLand")
    && !$(blocks[current[rot][3]+x]).hasClass("blockLand"))
    {
    //something to happen here ONCE!
    }
```

Because i want something inside to happen just once i think i cant use `for loop`.
So my question is: is there a possible way to reduce the conditions number? and how?

P.S.: Yes i figured out that i can use `flag` (`true/false`) inside and do my stuff outside this `if`, in another `if` - but i think that not always gonna work, because for every loop the flag will be different.

Comment: Add complete code, also add HTML, it might be helpful to optimize the code

Comment: It's all about logic, the other code ain't nothin to deal with this!

Comment: If your goal is to make it more readable, you can extract the atomic conditions to boolean functions or variables and check for them

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş you're just plain *wrong* about that. the other code has **everything** to do with this - it helps us find more efficient and simple solutions that we cannot see without it, it also gives us a background to work on as a base and remember, we're trying to help you - cooperate or say it if it's private.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş We're all here trying to help you. If you don't add complete code, the solution provided might not be optimal. Right now it is not clear what the array contains, what `x` is, and how the elements in DOM are placed.

Comment: Two users already understand me what i mean, so the problem might be in you...

Comment: @Tushar ..and also i don't want somebody to solve my problem completely, i am in process of learning, i ask question, and my question absolutely fits the stackoverflow requirements

Comment: The asker is trying to use a more efficient way of doing conditions than if statements. I think this might be a valuable question.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş Hi! how it was ? did it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var b = true;

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

    // In two lines for being clear, but it's possible just in one
    b = b && (current[rot][i] + x)<blocks.length 
    b = b && !$(blocks[current[rot][i]+x]).hasClass("blockLand"); 

    // You could speed it up this way. 
    if(!b) break;
}

if (b) {
    //something to happen here ONCE!
}
```

Comment: I'm working on it, it's kinda work. when i finish with it i will reply to you and gonna approve your answer (in 24 hours).

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking but let me know if there is anything else I can do.

JavaScript has a ternary (conditional operator) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

This operator allows you to assign true/false values based on an internal if/else condition.

Here is some code for you to explain this...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var one = 1;
  var two = 2;
  console.log(one > two ? "greater" : "not greater");
};
```

You can also use a Switch statement which you can read about here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.

Here is an example of a switch statement.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var string = "testing this out";
  switch (string) {
    case "testing this out":
      console.log('testing this out found in condition one');
      break;
    case "testing":
      console.log('found testing');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('not found');
      break;
  }
};
```

Let me know if I can improve this.